# Replace Eclipse with Sublime Text 2/3 for java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, sublimetext2

Has anyone managed to build out a way to use Sublime Text 2 (or 3) instead of eclipse for their java-based app? We've got java in eclipse (mac), with maven and git support. We don't 'build' in eclipse, per-se. Instead when necessary we just either refresh the projects or restart the tomcat server--usually though, we can just make changes and reload the browser.

To be clear, the app is single-page-architecture built on java/mysql, with a dojo javascript framework on the front end.

Suggestions?

Comment: YES! I have managed this with the following stack: Sublime Text 3, Javatar, JDebug (for remote debug), SublimeLinter and SublimeLinter-javac (for compile time error highlighting and import issues). If you are working with Maven, you will also need to configure the build system to use it, either long-hand, or with a plugin such as SublimeMaven.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with switching to SublimeText2/3 in almost any language.

- There are multiple `git` packages that help you with using it, such as full integration, merges and everything else you may need.
- Even if you would build or simply needed to restart the tomcat server you can write your own build system that will run everything you need just like you would manually do in terminal.
- SublimeText works exceptionally well with JS and it's frameworks as well as code-in-code - different languages one in another.
- [Maven package](https://github.com/nlloyd/SublimeMaven) is available

Now to the parts that you would probably miss when switching from other IDE's.

- IntelliSense - SublimeText has a package named CodeIntel that will help with that, but it's not working that good in comparison to other IDEs.
- MySQL - SublimeText has no way to integrate DB management.

Comment: Good answer, I found it useful. There was no mention of debugging tho, I guess the best option would be to use an external debugger?

Comment: @cosbor11 I suggest you to see the packages available [here](https://packagecontrol.io/), there are some debugging plugins for other languages, they allow breakpoints and logs, but I can't say I've seen one for Java. But better look yourself