# How to use sublime for java development

Tags: java, syntax-error, sublimetext2

I want to use sublime as development tool instead of eclipse, but although sublime enables to highlight the code, but how to detect the errors and compile the java code as eclipse does?

Thanks!

Comment: So, why do you want to use Sublime if Eclipse match your needs?

Comment: for fun I think.. and also when eclipse is running some code I want to use sublime to write some other code

Comment: So, use Sublime when Eclipse runs (even if you can write code in Eclipse when he's running code) then copy/paste it in Eclipse.

Comment: Strange definition of fun. You can still code in eclipse when your program is running. And you get a lot more useful features in eclipse (like debugging, refactoring support, junit integration).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace Eclipse with Sublime Text 2/3 for java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992250/replace-eclipse-with-sublime-text-2-3-for-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sublime Text is a *text editor*, not an IDE. You'll need to compile it from command line using `javac File.java`. And it won't highlight errors for you.

If you want a simpler text editor how Java, consider [jGrasp](http://www.jgrasp.org/) or [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/).

Comment: Sublime Text 2/3 has great support for syntax highlighting for Java.

Comment: @ArthurCollé I meant highlighting errors, I'll fix that.

Comment: `You'll need to compile it from command line using javac` Sublime Text actually allows customizable [**Build Systems**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html). `it won't highlight errors for you` It also has various [**linting plugins**](https://packagecontrol.io/search/linter).

Comment: This answer underlooks the capabilities of sublime text.

Answer (score 3):

All the answers above are totally correct: Sublime Text is a text editor, not an IDE. So you'll either use an IDE for your projects (for the ease) or use Sublime + cmd line (with a little bit of pain)

However, I personally kinda like it too, especially Sublime Text 3. So I use both: intellij for real/big projects and SBT3 for small things/Code Snippets(when I read books for example) (+ quick & repeatable unit tests to assert results, no need of a bare main()) that I want to try. And this can go very fast if you're used to SBT3 shortcuts (because it is a very lightweight and fast editor) instead of launching a full blown intellij instance + gradle + etc. just for those dimple things.

Another reason for using SBT for these simple things (especially when you are learning) is that you get rid of auto completion, auto import, etc. It forces you type everything and you learn a lot!

To enable highlighting + error check on SBT3, you need to install:

- Package Control
- SublimeLinter + SublimeLinter-javac from Package Control (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-javac )
- Seti_UX theme from Package Control (for great highlighting)

You can refer to this as an example:

[How to use JUnit with Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255962/how-to-use-junit-with-sublime-text-3)

Answer (score 1):

Sublime is not really ideal (imo) for Java development. If you don't want to use eclipse, you can take a look at intellij, my favorite IDE for Java and web projects.

Of course, you can use sublime for you Java projects. But you have to compile the java files. The way you do that is from terminal/dos is to write:

```
javac myJavaFile.java
```

and then you run the javac file:

```
java myJavaFile
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the multiple selection and other cool stuff in sublime for your java development then Intellij IDEA is your choise, you'll have more cool features that are just not possible with text editor.

I love sublime but that is not the case with compilable languages like java or C++...
There you can see Intellij in action http://tv.jetbrains.net/videocontent/refactoring-in-intellij-idea-live-by-robert-c-martin-uncle-bob