# How to use JUnit with Sublime Text 3

Tags: java, junit, sublimetext3

This is a two part question. I'm trying to use JUnit for a project I'm working on in Sublime Text 3. The file setup I have looks somewhat like this

```
Vulcan/
 Vulcan.sublime-project
 bin/
  ...
 src/
  core/
   org/
    vulcan/
     geom/
      Vector.java
      ... (other similar files in the same package)
  tests/
   org/
    vulcan/
     geom/
      VectorTest.java
      ... (relevant test files to match core/org/vulcan/geom/)
```

At the top of `Vector.java` and `VectorTest.java`, I have the line `package org.vulcan.geom`. Now, in my `sublime-project` file, I have set the source folder to `Vulcan/src/core/`, so that when I build it, `Vector.java` is compiled to `bin/org/vulcan/geom/Vector.class`, but what this means is that upon building the whole project, the `tests/` folder gets ignored and is not built to `bin/`.

I attempted to fix this by setting the source folder to `Vulcan/src/`, but that causes a bunch of errors in `org/vulcan/geom/`, saying that it cannot find any of the class names in that package (I assume the fix for this would be to change the package from `org.vulcan.geom` to `core.org.vulcan.geom` but that would be a tedious process).

**Question 1:** So how can I set up my project such that the `tests/` get compiled along with the `core/` when I build the whole project?

**Question 2:** With this file structure, how would I run the tests in `tests/` with `JUnit` (each `.java` file in `tests/` is a test class runnable by `JUnit`)? I've read the tutorials and I see that I can either run them from the command line (which I'm not quite sure how to do), or I can create a class whose `main` method runs all the tests. If I choose the latter option, where would I put the "runner" class? Would I put it in `tests/org/vulcan/geom/`, or in `tests/org/vulcan/`, or in `tests/org/`? And how would I run it from Sublime Text 3?

Comment: Can I ask why you aren't using an IDE like eclipse? Just curious, I use sublime (2) but not for java.

Comment: I like the Sublime Text interface and aesthetic much more. That's it. I know it's kind of a dumb reason, so I'm planning to switch to Eclipse in the near future, but for now I'm stuck with Sublime Text.

Comment: I use a sublime theme in eclipse, so its just the same but with the power of an IDE ! :)

Comment: @KevinPaton I do exactly the same thing as well! Why use sublime for java development when you can just change the look and feel of eclipse to sublime?

Comment: @OP It appears that the Javatar project have marked this as an enhancement for their plugin (see https://github.com/spywhere/Javatar/issues/19). In the meantime, could this not be achieved using a custom Build System definition?

Answer (score 2):

**About question 1:**

- install Package Control
- install Sublime Linter
- install Sublime Linter javac

edit Vulcan.sublime-project and add the following

```
"SublimeLinter": 
{
    "linters": 
    {
        "javac": 
        {
            "args": 
            [
                "-cp",
                "/usr/share/java/junit4.jar",
                "-sourcepath",
                "${project}/src/core:${project}/src/tests"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In the -cp you can add whatever .jar libraries are needed for compilation. In the -sourcepath you can add multiple sources of your project (beware to use unique package names). Both can take multiple paths separated by ":".

Those two parameters are actually javac cli parameters, so you can look up javac man page for more functionality.

If you use the setup above, every time you save a .java file in sublime, javac will compile it and create a .class file in the same dir. Sublime linter will show you compilation errors and warnings in the sidebar gutter.

**About question 2:**

If you want to test everything that's inside vulcan, TestRunner.java should be in tests/org/vulcan. If you want to test everything that's inside geom TestRunner.java should be in tests/org/vulcan/geom.

TestRunner.java example - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html#juniteclipse_code

But for running the tests, you must save all your files so they get compiled and after run

```
cd .../Vulcan/src/tests
java -cp .:/usr/share/java/junit4.jar org.vulcan.TestRunner
```

**Out of topic - why use sublime for java:**

If you use less autocomplete, autoimport, copy/paste - you learn faster, your attention to details become better and in the long run you are writing correct code faster.